# jQuery POST redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/[object Object]

Tags: jquery, url, post, localhost

In my jQuery POST request, the url gets directed to local host always (with a message  [http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/[object Object]](http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/[object%20Object]) )

With a jQuery GET this works fine (connects to the external URL).

How can I change the POST behavior to access the specified URL?

```
var tmpurl='https://myhost.com/message';
$.post({
  data: {
   'v': value,
   'key' : 'MyKey'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: tmpurl,
  success: function(response) {
  console.log("success!", response);  
 }
});
```

Comment: What do u mean redirect? and also try using json as dataType instead of jsonp

Comment: I mean it does not use the intended url (https://myhost.com/message) as the target, but tries to connect to localhost. jsonp is for cross domain requests. Tried with json dataType, but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making an ajax call over https, I will recommend you to have an extra `/` at the end like `/message/`. For crossDomain requests use `crossDomain: true.`

```
var tmpurl='https://myhost.com/message/';
$.post({
  data: {
   'v': value,
   'key' : 'MyKey'
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  url: tmpurl,
  success: function(response) {
  console.log("success!", response);  
 }
});
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: @RajCherla Are you sure the server doesnt cause the redirect

Comment: No it is not a server re-direct. Looks like the POST is setting the url to a default.

Comment: @RajCherla Try checking the network headers. Visit this link, it might help you. https://processwire.com/talk/topic/10849-problem-ajax-requests-getting-301-redirects/ . Try this plugin to gain more info on headers. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo

Comment: @Shubham..will analyze and revert. Thanks